# Share castle windsor singleton instance across multiple components

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I want to be able to do this:

```
<component id="Component1" service="Foo.IFoo, Foo" type="Foo.Bar, Foo" lifestyle="singleton" />
<component id="Component2" service="Foo.IFoo, Foo" type="Foo.Bar, Foo" lifestyle="singleton" />
```

Such that when I do this:

```
IFoo foo = m_container.Resolve<IFoo>("Component1");
```

Or this:

```
IFoo foo = m_container.Resolve<IFoo>("Component2");
```

..I get the same singleton instance, not a seperate instance per component.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you register two components if you want just one?

Comment: In the actual code, the component name is an interface name. I want to be able to map ISomething to a singleton instance and also map ISomethingElse to the same instance.

All I have to go off at runtime is the interface name, so I need to look up the shared instance via the castle config.

Comment: I've worked around this issue without using Castle, but if it is possible I'd like to use it. It's for a cache, where N number of interfaces resolve to any given cache instance, hence I potentially need multiple components for one singleton instance.

Answer (score 0):

If all you have is the interface "Name" at runtime how are you planning to call the generic Resolve<> method on the windsor container?  If you truely only want one singleton instance of IFoo regardless of the comopnent "Name" then just register one as a singleton and call:

```
IFoo foo = m_container.Resolve<IFoo>();
```

If you are looking to have multiple interfaces return the same component you can look at using Forward types.